# Find for which values of the real parameter $k$ one of the roots is with 3 greater than the other one

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

I have to find for which values of the real parameter $k$ one of the roots of:
$$x^2-15x+k^2-10=0$$

is with $3$ greater than the other one.

So, demand $D=b^2-4ac=(-15)^2-4(k^2-10)=15^2-4k^2+40=225-4k^2+40=265-4k^2 > 0$ (I am not sure if it can be $0$, because if it is, the roots are equal?). Here, we get $k^2<\frac{265}{4}$. I don't know how to simplify this. Then I tried to use Vieta's formulas, but it seems useless at the end. $x_1=x_2+3$ and $x_1+x_2=\frac{-b}{a}=x_2+3+x_2=2x_2+3$

$x_1x_2=\frac{c}{a}=x_2(x_2+3)=x_2^2+3x^2$.

Comment: $a,b$ are the roots with $a-b=3$. Use the identity $(a-b)^2=(a+b)^2-4a b$

Comment: @Lozenges, I really don't see how this helps.

Comment: @Lozenges, can you explain to me?

Comment: $a-b=3$, $a+b=15$, and $a b=k^2-10$. We get $9=15^2-4(k^2-10)$

Comment: $$x^2-15x+(k^2-10)=0\\x^2-(2t+3)x+t(t+3)=0$$ are the same equations so one has the system
$$2t+3=15\\t^2+3t=k^2-10$$ Thus $$k^2=36+18+10=64$$

Answer (score 2):

If the two roots of the polynomial are $\alpha$ and $\beta$ then the polynomial factors as
$$x^2-15x+k^2-10=(x-\alpha)(x-\beta).$$
Expanding the right hand side immediately shows that 
$$\alpha+\beta=15\qquad\text{ and }\qquad \alpha\beta=k^2-10.$$
Now you want one of the roots to be $3$ more than the other, i.e. without loss of generality you want
$$\alpha=\beta+3.$$
Then it follows that
$$15=\alpha+\beta=2\beta+3,$$
which shows that $\beta=6$ and $\alpha=9$. Then
$$k^2-10=\alpha\beta=9\times6=54,$$
and so $k^2=64$ which means that $k=\pm8$.

Comment: Sorry, but we haven't studied complex numbers. I am trying to get only the part with real numbers in your solution, but I don't understand how did you get $k = \pm 8$.

Comment: Can you explain to me?

Comment: No need for complex numbers, only Vieta, don't worry.

Comment: @Valeri The line above shows that $k^2-10=54$ and so $k^2=64$. Hence $k=\pm\sqrt{64}=\pm8$.

Answer (score 0):

Using the quadratic formula:

$x = \dfrac{15\pm\sqrt{265-4k^2}}{2}$

We want one root to be $3$ away from the other one, so we let

$\dfrac{15+\sqrt{265-4k^2}}{2} = a$

$\dfrac{15-\sqrt{265-4k^2}}{2} = a+3$

Rearranging, we get

$2a-15=\sqrt{265-4k^2}$

and

$15-2(a+3) = \sqrt{265-4k^2}$

Equating these, we find $a$, and we can put this back into either equation to find our value(s) for $k$. Also note that we do not know which root is bigger than which, so we could also have tried $a-3$ for the RHS of the second equation. However, if you try both, can you see why this doesn't matter?

Comment: Thank you for your response! I appreciate your help! But I didn't understand is $k^2<\dfrac{265}{4}$ necessary, and how can I simplify it?

Comment: You want to equation those last 2 equations, so that 2a-15 = 15-2(a+3), then solve to get a = 6. Then by putting a into the first equation, we get 2(6)-15 = sqrt(265-4k^2) or -3 = sqrt(265-4k^2). Once you rearrange that you'll get a number that square roots nicely.